# Need help with script, runs on command line but not in script

Tags: bash, shell-script

so I have the following which runs if I run it on the command line, but gives this error within a bash script:

```
sudo -u $usr rm -rf "${htmldir}"/!("awstatsicons"|"awstats-icon"|"icon"|"roundcube"|"phpmyadmin"|"stats"|"htusers")
```

Note, in the bash script, the line above I've specified:  "shopt -s extglob".
If I add in the usr and htmldir variables on the command line, set the "shopt -s extglob" and copy that line exactly, it then behaves as it should.
However running it from a script, it gives the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I've tried some permutations, but not coming right. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How exactly are you running the script? does it have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang?

Comment: Hi @steeldriver yes, it's a standard bash script with '''#!/bin/bash''' starting it off

Comment: how about `find` with -maxdepth -type -not -name -delete flags

Comment: hi @alecxs, I really wanted to use the rm command. As mentioned this works on the command line itself, I'm trying to find out why it's not working within a script

Comment: post the output of `hexdump -C script`

Comment: @alecxs here you go:
[link](https://gist.github.com/neural-oD/c0bca0a6e0f03a84676b50059872db5e)

Comment: file looks clean, no hidden characters or carriage returns. change the shebang to `#!/bin/dash` it seems `!(exclude)` is not working on bash

Comment: i really have no clue why it doesn't work even with `extglob` maybe the settings do not effect `sudo` shell. Maybe read the man page for `shopt` https://stackoverflow.com/q/55546727

Comment: I feel like I am trying to reconstruct a bash script that I can see through the fog. Show us the script.

Comment: @alecxs Ok, so I need to firstly apologise. I copied code from my script, as it was long and convoluted, and created a new file which I posted. My error was in thinking I "knew" where the issue was. In fact you were right on the money.... When I went to the "original" script I had the same issue. What set me right, was the fact that you'd asked for the hexdump... I then went in and deleted all "empty" lines, and made sure I had no white space after characters on the line. Once this was sorted out, the script ran...
Thanks once again alecxs - guys like you make sites like this rock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so basically I had posted a snippet of my problem. However, @alecxs was right on the money. I must have had something with a hidden character, or "white space" that was causing issues.
I went in and deleted all the "empty" rows, made sure that everything was deleted after the last visible character on every line.
Then ran the script, and it all worked.
Thanks once again to @alecxs

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the shell interactive and use `history -p` to interpret ! characters:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
eval $(history -p <your statement involving ! expansion>)
```

And before you call the shell script, you need to save the history:

```
history -a
```

Example:

```
cat jt
#!/bin/bash -i
eval `history -p !df`

df /; history -a
./jt
```

Comment: Please note that the OPs intention is _not_ to use the `!` for history expansion, but as a negation for the following OR-type filename alternative `( ... | ... | ... )`, so the OP wants to `rm` all _files that are not called_ "awstatsicons" or "awstats-icon" or "icon" or "roundcube" or "phpmyadmin" or "stats" or "htusers".